# Can't connect to Node.js app with Nginx running on port 3000

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, nginx, https

I have a Node.js app running on a Raspberry Pi with Express listening on port 3000 also using the https module rather than the http one. I've properly configured my SSL certificate in Node.js and it throws no errors. I then setup Nginx to redirect all 80 and 443 (http and https) traffic to 3000, here is my config

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;

        ssl_certificate /home/pi/Desktop/SSL/www_randomchat_tech.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/pi/Desktop/SSL/example_com.key;

location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;                                                                                 
    }
}
```

When I attempt to connect locally (through http://10.0.0.236) I get the Nginx 502 bad gateway page. I checked my logs for Nginx and got this

```
*11 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 
10.0.0.48, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/", host: 
"10.0.0.236"
2020/08/29 03:30:44 [error] 3373#3373: *11 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response 
header from upstream, client: 10.0.0.48, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "10.0.0.236"
2020/08/29 03:30:44 [error] 3373#3373: *11 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 
10.0.0.48, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"http://localhost/favicon.ico", host: "10.0.0.236", referrer: "https://10.0.0.236/"
```

A couple of days ago I was using IpTables to route all traffic and it was working until I implemented SSL and then I removed all that to use Nginx. I've checked if port 3000 has node running on it and if it's open and it does. Going to 10.0.0.236:3000 delivers the app just fine.

I'm assuming I setup my Nginx config wrong and that's the problem here. I looked up a dozen different articles and videos and tried this one. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are trying to accomplish? You want the RasPI to be a NodeJS server, and all incoming request to your PC to be routed to the RasPI Node.JS-Server?

Comment: Sorry I completely overlooked this! I am using socket.io to make a simple chat app. The RasPi runs the node server and has Nginx on it to route the ports. All traffic from my router on ports 80 and 443 get directed to the pi. I now realize I am going to have to do more work to get socket.io working as well.